# Mounting a filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, mountpoint

I know how to use mounting in linux and have used it many a times but I am not able to understand what mount actually means in operating system,its benefits and practical usage?
I have searched it on various sites but could not find useful links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mount` means **binding** a device such as hard-drive to your file-system under **"/" root directory .**

For example home directory `/home` could be another **hard-disk** , when you mount it will seems /home .

Another example when you connect a usb , how can you access it if its not mounted , so mount enable you to access your device.

So mount tell your **Os** that a devices is linked to root top directory and is **ready for use** .

**Note :** You can apply permissions to mount point , and if you want to save a mount after reboot you should write it in **fstab** .

Answer (score 0):

Benefits:

1. Control access to drive
2. No unnecessary read/write operations in a drive that you don't use
3. When unmounting successfully you are sure that all your data has been writen to the drive
4. Lower power consumption
5. Security benefits: no software can access a drive before it is mounted and mounting requires Administrator privileges

Practical usage: if you don't have UPS you can consider an unmounted drive as safely removed (like USB) in case of power loss.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29)